# Distributed cache or maybe database to send data to clients?

Tags: .net, notifications, distributed

I need help with a common senario.....

I have a central database or datastore in some way. Then I have a bunch of Win-clients. These clients all needs a part of this data in a local datastore of some kind. They also need to update their local datastore if the central datastore is updated.

I think this must be a common senario but I cant find any simple solutions to it. Of course I can implement a pubsub system using queues or something like that. But is there another way? (hopefully simpler or at least smarter :) )

Comment: why do you thing pub-sub is not smarter?

Comment: Since I have to write the changetracking code on the serverside and the update code on the client side eachtime I use this technic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html) offers bi-directional replication of data and supports working in a disconnected way. Sounds like a good match for your high-level requirements.

Comment: Maybe these NoSql databases is the answer. I see that some of them support notifications. Thank you!